# How do i change the following input line using SED?

Tags: unix, sed

How do i change the following input line using SED ?

Input - bus_ln in ('abc');

Required O/P - bus_ln in ('def','xyz');

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
sed "s/\([^(]*\)('[^']*')/\1('def','xyz')/" inputfile
```

It will replace whatever is between the parentheses.

Input:

```
bus_ln in ('abc');
foo('bar');
baz aaa bbb ('ccc ddd') some more text
```

Output:

```
bus_ln in ('def','xyz');
foo('def','xyz');
baz aaa bbb ('def','xyz') some more text
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed substitute command:

```
echo "bus_ln in ('abc');" | sed "s/bus_ln in ('abc');/bus_ln in ('def','xyz');/"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "Input - bus_ln in ('abc');" | ruby -e 'print gets.gsub(/(.*\()(.[^;]*)(\);)/,"\\1\047def\047,\047xyz\047\\3")'
Input - bus_ln in ('def','xyz');
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo "bus_ln in ('abc');" | sed "s/'.*'/'def','xyz'/"
bus_ln in ('def','xyz');
```

This uses `"`'s to surround the sed commands which may sometimes lead to unexpected results.
Using `'`'s instead is clumsy (in comparison) but more predictable:

```
echo "bus_ln in ('abc');" | sed 's/'\''.*'\''/'\''def'\',\''xyz'\''/'
bus_ln in ('def','xyz');
```

Where `'\''` represents a single `'` and `'\',\''` represents `','`